# Adding Placeholder

Tags: tinymce

```
tinymce.init({
        mode: "exact",
        elements: "Grievance",
        forced_root_block: "",
        theme: "advanced",
        paste_text_sticky: true,
        paste_text_sticky_default: true,
        plugins: "wordcount,paste,autolink,advlink,contextmenu,fullscreen,nonbreaking,template,inlinepopups,style",
        //plugins: "wordcount,paste,autolink,advlink,fullscreen,nonbreaking,template,inlinepopups,style",

        // Theme options
        //theme_advanced_buttons1: "bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,undo,redo,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,fullscreen",
        //theme_advanced_buttons2: "cut,copy,paste,|,cleanup,removeformat,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,hr,charmap",
        //theme_advanced_buttons1: "cut,copy,paste,removeformat,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,|,formatselect,bold,italic,underline,forecolor,backcolor,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyfull,|,link,unlink,|,fullscreen",
        theme_advanced_buttons1: "cut,copy,paste,removeformat,|,undo,redo,|,bullist,numlist,outdent,indent,|,bold,italic,underline,|,fullscreen",
        //theme_advanced_blockformats: 'p,h1,h2,h4,h4,h5,h6',
        theme_advanced_toolbar_location: "top",
        theme_advanced_toolbar_align: "left",
        //theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
        theme_advanced_resizing: true,
        theme_advanced_path: false,
        content_css: "/css/admin.css",  
        selector: 'textarea',  // change this value according to your HTML
        setup: function (editor) {
            editor.on('init', function(){
            if (tinymce.get('Text').getContent() == ''){
                tinymce.get('Text').setContent("<p id='#Grievance'>Please put Case Information here</p>");
            }
            });
            //and remove it on focus
            editor.on('focus',function(){
              $('iframe').contents().find('#Grievance').remove();
            });
    }
    });
```

I am trying to add a Placeholder but I am getting  "editor.on is not a function" so how do I add a place holder please without going to version 5 as that seems to be completely different. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I managed it in the end using Blur and Focus. Thanks